# Monge formulation of Optimal Transport

Tags: real-analysis, optimal-transport

I'm reading these notes trying to understand a bit more about optimal transport
[https://www.math.cmu.edu/~mthorpe/OTNotes](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Emthorpe/OTNotes)

Can someone help me explain the following on pg 6

We say that $T: X \to Y$ transports $\mu \in P(x)$ to $v \in P(Y)$, and we call T a transport map if
$$v(B) = \mu(T^{-1}(B))$$ for all $v$-measurable sets $B$

If the function T is injective then we can equivalently say that
$ν(T(A)) = \mu(A)$ for all $\mu$-measurable A

Q1. Why is there equality when its injective? Shouldn't it be equal if bijective?

Q2.What is meant by $v$-measurable sets?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. It is also equal if it is bijective, since in that case is is injective. But only injectivity is needed to replace one formulation by the other.

Q2: You have measures defined on $X$ and $Y$ ($\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively). $\nu$-measurable means a subset of $Y$ that is in the sigma algebra of measurable subsets of $Y$.

The whole point of this construction is that $T$ preserves the measure of the sets, so it is some sort of isomorphism in the sense of measures.

Comment: See my comment to Anonymous M's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**For Q1**, this is an instance of a general fact you will likely find handy to keep in the back pocket.

In general, for a function $T:X\to Y$ and a subset $B$ of $Y$, we can define the preimage of $B$ via $T$ as a set. You probably know the definition. We denote this set $T^{-1}(B)$.

If a function $T:X\to Y$ is *injective*, we can define an honest-to-goodness *function* $T^{-1}:T(X)\to X$ by defining $T^{-1}(y)$ to be the single element of the set $T^{-1}(\{y\})$. This is a slight abuse of notation because we're using $T^{-1}$ in two ways. Since $T$ is injective, $T^{-1}(\{y\})$ contains a single element. The function $T^{-1}$ is called a *left inverse* because $T^{-1}\circ T = 1_X$, i.e. $(T^{-1}\circ T)(x) = x$ for all $x\in X$.

Suppose $T$ is a transport map. Then $\nu(T(A)) = \mu(T^{-1}(T(A))$, and it is not hard to show that $T^{-1}(T(A)) = (T^{-1}\circ T)(A)$ where $T^{-1}$ is a left inverse of $T$. So $\mu(T^{-1}(T(A)) = \mu((T^{-1}\circ T)(A)) = \mu(1_X(A)) = \mu(A)$.

The function $T$ is bijective if it has a left inverse and a right inverse. But you only need a left inverse for this observation, so injective is enough.

**For Q2,**
As GReyes says, a measure $\nu$ on $Y$ is a function $\nu:\Sigma \to \overline{\mathbb{R}} $ with special properties, where $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$. A probability measure is one where also $\nu(Y) = 1$, which you will almost certainly find to be an important assumption as you study optimal transport problems. So a $\nu$-measurable set $B$ simply means that $B\in\Sigma$.

Comment: This is not the usual definition of $\nu$-measurable set. Instead, a $\nu$-measurable set is an element of the Caratheodory completion of $\Sigma$ with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: @MaoWao I encourage you to look at the notes that are linked, these things are all specifically Radon measures on Polish spaces. And more specifically, even if it is some subtle difference that it is a useful one for a student asking Q1.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say with your first sentence. I am just pointing out that $\nu$-measurable sets are elements of a very specific $\sigma$-algebra. In the context of Radon measures, this is the $\mu$-completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and not the Borel $\sigma$-algebra itself. And subtle or not, one should at least point out where one is deliberately imprecise.

Comment: @MaoWao This is not imprecise, simply not detailed. I am taking $\nu$ to be a measure, not an outer measure. The notes linked don't specify a definition. It appears there are a few conflicting definitions of a Radon measure in the literature: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109505/about-the-definition-of-borel-and-radon-measures. The Wikipedia article (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure) appears to follow Folland, ref V in the MO answer, which takes Randon measures to be defined on Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I think the answer is at the right level of depth.

Comment: Again, my point has little to do with the definition of a Radon measure. If $\nu$ is any measure on the measurable space $(Y,\mathcal F)$, then a $\nu$-measurable set is an element of $\mathcal F^\nu$, the $\nu$-completion of $\mathcal F$. Saying that it's an element of $\mathcal F$ is at least a very non-standard definition.